# Exchange 2010/2013 TransportAgent Content Conversion for Internal Recipients

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, exchange-transport-agents, tnef

I am trying to create a `TransportAgent` that reroutes an internal email to a remote server for further processing, but the email comes over in Microsoft's internal TNEF format (no content conversion is being applied). I would like it to be in the same format that would be used if the email was going to an external recipient.

I am currently using a `RoutingAgent` to reroute the internal emails to the remote server. If someone can explain why this happens in terms of the Categorizer's pipeline, that would be very helpful too, even if I can't avoid it. This agent will be implemented for both Exchange 2010 and 2013, in case the answer differs based on the version of Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Exemple using reflexion ItemConversion.convertAnyMimeToMimeMethod method

```
var mimeDocument = new MimeDocument();
using (var mimeDocumentLoadStream = mimeDocument.GetLoadStream())
{
    ConvertAnyMimeToMimeMethod(email.Message.MimeDocument, mimeDocumentLoadStream);
}
var convertedEmail = EmailMessage.Create(mimeDocument);


private static void ConvertAnyMimeToMimeMethod(MimeDocument documentIn, Stream mimeOut)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage");
    var outboundConversionOptionsType = assembly?.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.OutboundConversionOptions");
    var outboundOptionsConstructor = outboundConversionOptionsType?.GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        new[] { typeof(string) },
        null);
    var outboundOptions = outboundOptionsConstructor?.Invoke(new object[] { "OurDomain.tld" });
    var itemConversionType = assembly?.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ItemConversion");
    var convertAnyMimeToMimeMethod = itemConversionType?.GetMethod(
        "ConvertAnyMimeToMime",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
        null,
        new[] { documentIn.GetType(), mimeOut.GetType(), outboundOptions?.GetType() },
        null);

    convertAnyMimeToMimeMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { documentIn, mimeOut, outboundOptions });
}
```